# Converting linked list into queue (moving the nodes)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue

I need some help with the logic whereby I need to create a queue from linked list. So I was given all these code from the question:

```
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode; // You should not change the definition of ListNode

typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;   // You should not change the definition of LinkedList

typedef struct _queue
{
    LinkedList ll;
} Queue;
```

And by using enqueue, dequeue and isEmptyQueue, I am supposed to create a queue from linked list.

So the logic that I have gotten is:

```
 Loop thru list size
      enqueue linked list head node
      removeNode to update linkedlist head node
```

Is that logic correct? I need a head start and thanks in advance.

So I have came out with this code to create a queue from linked list:

However, it crashes my program with no error message. I tried with dummy value enqueue(q,1) and it still crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: "*enqueue the removed node from linked list*" err, what?

Comment: @alk I think it means: enqueue the node that was removed from the linked list.

Comment: @alk, its more like "*enqueue [the removed node from linked list]*"

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I enqueue the linkedlist->head, then I execute the removeNode until linkedlist size = 0

Comment: Sry, but I somehow fully seem to miss the point of this question ... :-S

Comment: Actually I am trying to grab the logic before working on it :)

Comment: Why to enqueue when having removed it. Why to remove when wanting to enqueue it? It this a language translation issue, or am I suffering a temp brain laps?

Comment: Because I need to create a queue based on linked list. So I was thinking to enqueue the head node from linked list, then remove the head node and iterate until linked list size becomes 0. Is that correct?

Comment: "*enqueuing*" means "*putting **into** the queue*" :-S

Comment: "*and iterate until linked list size becomes 0.*" to achieve what?

Comment: @alk, linked list  -> Queue. For that, **select the first node in the linked list, enqueue the value in queue, free that node, move to the next node in the linked list, repeat until linked list is empty**

Comment: I **did** get the question completely wrong. Thanks @Haris. I understood to use the implementation of a  Linked List to build a Queue from, and **not** to move the nodes of a linked list into a queue.

Comment: @alk, actually it is a little confusing, the code doesn't seem to do what the algorithm says, and m pretty sure the code is wrong.

Comment: The title's "*converting*" is quiet ambiguous also. Clarified the title.

Comment: Can you post some more code, as, how you created the link list and the definition of structure.

Comment: @20 Cents Your code is wrong because one function of the queue uses method remove(&que->l, 0); of the list but the list has method int removeNode(LinkedList *ll, int index) that is their names do not coincide.

Comment: post code for `findNode()` also

Comment: I think the problem was with enqueue(). I did a mistake earlier on and I have updated the question. However, when I try with dummy values enqueue(&q, 1). The queue printed out was empty. Any ideas?

Comment: @20Cents - The title doesn't make much sense. My guess is the idea is to implement a queue using the linked list structures provided. The normal implementation of a queue / list only allows nodes to be appended to the end of the list and removed from the front of the list, along with functions to return the first or last node of a linked list, similar to std::queue. I assume that this isn't to be a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is correct, but i would add a little more detail to make it easier to code

```
Loop through the link list, selecting nodes one by one (until NULL)
    select a node;
    enqueue the value to the queue;
    Free the memory of that enqueued node;
    adjust the pointers to point to the next node in the linked list;
```

**Edit**

Lets write the algorithm in a little detail

```
while(head != NULL)
//Loop to traverse the linked list, just as you would while displaying each node

    enqueue( que, head->item);
    //This function will work just like a normal enqueue() function
    //It should take the item, and insert it in the queue and nothing else
    //I would recommend use an array for the queue

    temp = head;          //save the current node address to free later
    head = head -> next;  //go to next node in the linked list
    free(temp);           //free the previous node
```

Comment: while (l->size) {
  enqueue(q, ll->head->item);
  removeNode(l, 0);
 } I came out with this but it crahses my program. Any ideas?

Comment: @20Cents, wat does removeNode suppose to do.

Comment: It was posted as part of the question. Basically it just removing node from linked list with a specified index. I am executing removeNde(l, 0) so basically I am removing from the front all the way until the size = 0

Comment: Sorry sorry I realized that the pseudo code from the question was wrong after I actually wrote the code and forget to update it. What I am trying to do is create a queue from linked list. But the solution you provided still crashing the program :(

Comment: @20Cents You've gone from asking about the algorithm to asking about the code. Best if you post a new question with your actual code (or at least update the current question with the real code).

Comment: Sorry but what should be inside the enqueue(). Am I doing correctly from the question?

Comment: @20Cents, it should have the general `enqueue()` code. Go through the `queue` basics for that.

Comment: But from my lecture slides, I was taught that we should execute insertNode inside enqueue(). Any ideas which part I did wrongly?

Comment: @20Cents, i guess what they want you to do is use another function `insertNode()` to insert. Not sure though..

Answer (score 1):

Truly speaking I have understood nothing.

You need not to convert a linked list to the queue. All you need is to initialize data member `ll` of the queue with the list.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode; // You should not change the definition of ListNode

typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;   // You should not change the definition of LinkedList


int insert( LinkedList *ll, int index, int value )
{
    if ( index < 0 || index > ll->size ) return -1;

    ListNode *tmp = malloc( sizeof( ListNode ) );

    tmp->item = value;

    if ( ll->head == NULL )
    {
        tmp->next = ll->head;
        ll->head = tmp;
    }
    else
    {        
        ListNode *current = ll->head; 

        while ( --index ) current = current->next;
        tmp->next = current->next;
        current->next = tmp;
    }

    ++ll->size;

    return 0;
}

void list_output( const LinkedList *ll )
{
    for ( ListNode *current = ll->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->item );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}

typedef struct _queue
{
    LinkedList ll;
} Queue;

void queue_output( const Queue *q )
{
    list_output( &q->ll );
}    

int main( void )
{
    LinkedList lst = { 0, 0 };
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) insert( &lst, i, i );

    list_output( &lst );

    Queue q = { lst };

    lst = ( LinkedList )  { 0, 0 };

    queue_output( &q );

     // call here the method that free allocated memory of the queue

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

That is the queue now is the owner of the allocated nodes. The list in turn is empty.

It means that you indeed converted a list into a queue.

If you mean to copy elements of a list into the queue (it is a different operation compared with the converting operation) then the logic is the following

Traverse the list the same way as you would traverse it to output its element and call method `enqueue` of the queue for each data value of the node of the list

```
for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
{
    enqueue( que, head->x );
}
```

The list itself will be unchanged.

If you need to delete nodes of the list after the copy operation when you can call the method of the list that performs this operation.

Take into account that there is no need to dynamically allocate a list or a queue. For example a declaration of the list could look like

```
typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;   // You should not change the definition of LinkedList

LinkedList lst = { 0, 0 };
```

It is the nodes of the list that are allocated dynamically.

The same is valid for the Queue.

You can declare a queue the following way

```
typedef struct _queue
{
    LinkedList ll;
} Queue;

Queue q = { { 0, 0 } };
```

If you have a list then to convert it to the queue it is enough to write

```
q.ll = lst;
lst = ( LinkedList ) { 0, 0 };
```

Also this method

```
void enqueue(Queue *que, int x)
{
    int counter = 0;
    insert(&(que->l), counter++, x);
}
```

does not make sense. And moreover the Queue does not have data member `l`. It has data member `ll`

You need to append nodes to the queue. So you have to use the value of data member `size` of the queue as an index where the new element must be inserted.

So the method should look like

```
void enqueue( Queue *que, int x )
{
    insert( &que->ll, que->ll.size, x) ;
}
```

Comment: Actually the question was about to create a queue (linked-list-based) by enqueuing all integers storing in the linked list

Comment: @20Cents It means that you  need just to copy data values of the list into the queue.

Comment: I see I see. Seems like I have misunderstood the question :(. So I just need to implement the for loop in my enqueue()?

Comment: @20Cents I would like to point out, that if you don't need the linked list after being copied then you need to free the nodes as well.

Comment: Wait a minute, I am confused. So from the createQueueFromLinkedList(), I am executing your for loop. Then in the enqueue(), I am executing insertNode(). Am I correct?

Comment: Can you help me check the question? I have removed unnecessary parts. With the latest code as above, when I am printing queue, I get empty queue. I was thinking is it because of the counter++ from enqueue() always start from 0?

Comment: @20Cents why `insertNode()` in `enqueue()`?

Comment: It was the function prototypes which I were given enqueue() and createQFrmLl()

Comment: @Haris  If the list is not need then there is no need to copy its elements in the queue. It is enough to assign the list to the data member list of the queue and zero initialize the list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thats true, didn't think about that :).. Same happened to my answer btw, down-vote!!

Comment: The list will be needed to print out the element.

Comment: But I thought the insert() prototype is int insert(LinkedList *ll, int index, int value)

Answer (score 0):

```
void createQFrmLl(LinkedList *ll, Queue * q)
{
    while (ll->size) 
    {
        enqueue(q, ll->head->item); <-- CHANGE done here (passing 'q' instead of &q)
        removeNode(ll, 0);
    }
}
```

enqueue() expects 'Queue *' but you are passing 'Queue **', hence, inside enqueue() dereferencing q->ll is crashing since q is wrong memory address.

Comment: So basically when I am using &q it means that itis Queue** ?

Comment: You are right. In createQFrmLL(), 2nd input argument is 'Queue *q' and when inside the function, you use &q -> this means memory address which contains ' Queue * ' (the address pointing to Queue) hence it becomes ' Queue ** '